# submit the checked radio button value on form submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

This is my code for radio button and a textbox to check the selected value is properly got from radio button:
I want that radio button value should be submited on form submit.

```
<form name="send-form" class="send-form" method="POST">

    <input name="n1" type="text" class="Textbox" id="n1" />
    <input name="button" type="submit" class="SHN" id="button" value="GO"/>

    @Html.RadioButton("Yes", "0", true) Yes;
    @Html.RadioButton("No","1", false ) No;
</form>
```

This is the code to submit the radio button value using jquery:

```
$(".send-form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // get selected value
        var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='option']:checked");

        // check if an option was selected
        if (selected.length > 0) {
            selectedValue = selected.attr("id");
            $.post('somefile', {"option" : selectedValue}, function() {

                         // whatt to do here  

            });     
        }
    });
```

This is the code to assign the radio value to the text box.

```
function getRadio() {
        var n1 = document.getElementById('n1');
        var button = document.getElementById(radio);
        n1.value = button.value;
    }
```

Comment: why the negative rating , please explain , i am mew here!

Comment: Please read following: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic